# Best way to handle IVs with lots of zeros

Tags: regression

I am trying to build a regression model. I have a number of IVs that contain a lot of zero values and a few positive values. They are not true zero values, they are place holders for missing data. The variables are measuring marketing activity, so they are set to zero when there is no activity. Because of this, I don’t have a linear relationship between x and y. No transformation seems to do anything I achieve linearity . What’s the best way to handle this type of data? The dependent is continuous.

Comment: Can you distinguish between the case where there really was zero activity and when the marketing data is truly missing?

Comment: Yes, I know exactly when it was ‘turned off’ ie the campaign ran and finished. So when it’s ‘off’ , I just have zeros in the dataset

Comment: It does not sound like you have any missing data at all. You have a bunch of actual zeros.

Comment: Ok. Each variable has about 90% of the values as 0. Any ideas how best to model these types of vars? No transformations allow me to get a linear relationship between x and y.